# Is "clear" chicken broth a thing?

Tags: broth, chicken-stock

A friend once intoned that I'm doing it wrong, and that to get a *clear* chicken broth one must keep the pot uncovered.

I'm loath to do that. An uncovered pot means one's home will smell like chicken unless the fan above is cranked up; it will humidify the place unnecessarily; and it wastes energy.

Is "clear" chicken broth a thing? Is a clear broth, unlike the kind-of opaque one that you see below, desirable? If yes, why is a clear broth desirable, and what's wrong with a somewhat-opaque chicken broth?

[image: unclear chicken broth]

Comment: I'd call that 'more clear than I'd actually want to eat'. You could strain it, but it really looks short on 'ingredient vs water'. What's your actual recipe/method?

Comment: I know that one of the Chinese restaurants near me has a ‘clear’ soup. (Ethnic Hui-style Sliced Beef with Clear Noodle Soup), but it’s beef, not chicken.  I suspect it’s a regional thing as to what you want your broth to look like

Answer (score 2):

[You can clarify broth and stock by using egg white.](https://www.bhg.com/recipes/how-to/cooking-basics/how-to-clarify-stock/) First strain, then you add a whipped egg white mixture to the broth. Decant and/or strain to get clarified broth.  You can repeat the process if necessary.  Remember, clear does not mean colorless.